# How to use Kitematic with Hyper-V enabled?

Tags: docker, hyper-v, kitematic

I have installed Docker for Windows (running Windows 10). Out of the box, Docker would not install an image on Hyper-V but I was able to get it work.

**Edit**:  I acquired Kitematic via the link from this screen:

[image]

Upon clicking download, I get a zip file via http.

Next, I copied Kitematic zip contents to c:\program files\docker\kitematic. When I run Kitematic from Docker menu, it gives me an error stating:

```
VirtualBox is not installed. Please install it via the Docker Toolbox.
```

I don't want to use VirtualBox, if at all possible because I have other software that uses Hyper-V.

Is it possible to get Kitematic to use Hyper-V?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you instal kitematic from its setup?

Comment: If you mean from Docker Toolbox, no.  My understanding is Docker Toolbox isn't required for windows 10.  The link I found through the docker for windows app, gave me a zip file, which I copied to location specified by docker for windows

Comment: I install toolbox and now Kitematic works fine for me on Native Hyper-V setup also. It has settings to use Virtualbox or native VM

Comment: I installed docker toolbox (on windows 10) and it still tried to use virtual box:  Command failed: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe -D create -d virtualbox .....

Comment: I installed it yesterday to check on my WIndows 10 laptop and it works fine, so not sure why you getting that error

Comment: Try installing it from this link `https://download.docker.com/win/stable/DockerToolbox.exe`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You only need to delete **Kitematic** folder in `%APPDATA%` (C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming) and run Kitematic again.

Comment: Great guy! Tried different solutions ... and this one was successful!

Answer (score 2):

Next scenario worked for me:

1. disable hyper-v feature in windows
2. reinstall docker toolbox with Kitematic
3. reboot PC
4. run Kitematic
5. got to Settings -> uncheck "use virtualbox instead of native on next restart"
6. enable hyper-v back
7. restart PC
8. start Docker for windows
9. run Kitematic

Some of these steps may be redundant but it helped in my case.
I believe there must be some file or setting to tell Kitematic to use hyper-V instead of virtualbox provider but I wasn't managed to find another way of changing it.