# Getting error for Kitematic in windows for docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine, boot2docker, docker-for-windows, kitematic

I have setup docker on windows 10 machine.

My docker is working fine on the command line.

But Kitematic is not working and throwing below error

> Command failed: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe -D
>   create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default,Docker Machine
>   Version: 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9,Found binary path at C:\Program
>   Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe,Launching plugin server for
>   driver virtualbox,Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:2496,()
>   Calling .GetVersion,Using API Version 1,() Calling .SetConfigRaw,()
>   Calling .GetMachineName,(flag-lookup) Calling
>   .GetMachineName,(flag-lookup) Calling .DriverName,(flag-lookup)
>   Calling .GetCreateFlags,Found binary path at C:\Program Files\Docker
>   Toolbox\docker-machine.exe,Launching plugin server for driver
>   virtualbox,Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:2500,()
>   Calling .GetVersion,Using API Version 1,() Calling .SetConfigRaw,()
>   Calling .GetMachineName,(default) Calling .GetMachineName,(default)
>   Calling .DriverName,(default) Calling .GetCreateFlags,(default)
>   Calling .SetConfigFromFlags,(default) Calling
>   .PreCreateCheck,(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program
>   Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe --version,(default) DBG |
>   STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | 5.2.6r120293,(default) DBG |
>   },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG |
>   },(default) DBG | COMMAND: wmic computersystem get
>   hypervisorpresent,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default)
>   DBG | HypervisorPresent ,(default) DBG | TRUE ,(default) DBG |
>   ,(default) DBG | },Error with pre-create check: "This computer is
>   running Hyper-V. VirtualBox won't boot a 64bits VM when Hyper-V is
>   activated. Either use Hyper-V as a driver, or disable the Hyper-V
>   hypervisor. (To skip this check, use --virtualbox-no-vtx-check)",open
>   C:\Users\Shubham
>   Jain.docker\machine\machines\default\default\Logs\VBox.log: The
>   system cannot find the path specified.,notifying bugsnag: [Error with
>   pre-create check: "This computer is running Hyper-V. VirtualBox won't
>   boot a 64bits VM when Hyper-V is activated. Either use Hyper-V as a
>   driver, or disable the Hyper-V hypervisor. (To skip this check, use
>   --virtualbox-no-vtx-check)"],

I have installed docker tools and treid to used it's Kitematic but still getting this error.

I have tried to rename docker tool folder without space and set the same name in .sh still then Kitematic not able to locate it.

I have tried so many options available on the internet and due to same my docker actually corrupted. I have set it factory reset setting and then it starts working.

Example:

https://jayvilalta.com/blog/2016/04/28/installing-docker-toolbox-on-windows-with-hyper-v-installed/

If anyone already faced this issue in window 10 please share your experience.

reference screenshot

[image]

Any workaround will be helpful

Comment: I have the same issue. Others do as well. See [here on Github](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/4175). No solution so far.

Comment: It's almost a year still docker issue not resolve yet

Comment: Disable the hyper-v feature in `optionalfeatures.exe`.

Comment: Where this option present .. can you put some details

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution for this issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985175/how-to-use-kitematic-with-hyper-v-enabled):

> You only need to delete **Kitematic** folder in %APPDATA% (C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming) and run Kitematic again

Can you try on your side ?

Comment: Thanks Coli for the solution ... I will try it for sure :)